# Why can't we use/refer to derived table in subquery

Tags: sql

I wonder why can't a subquery use a derived table as its derived table (Query2), even though it can access the attribute of the derived table (Query1)?

Query1

```
select B.col1, col2 from dummy B
where B.col1 = (select col1 from dummy A where B.col1 = 'aa' and A.col1 = B.col1 limit 1);
```

Here we can use B.col1.

Query2

```
select B.col1, col2 from dummy B
where B.col1 = (select col1 from B where B.col1 = 'aa' limit 1);
```

Here we can't use B. The error says B doesn't exist.

You can find the sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7edac/8).

Comment: one is refering to the the alias and one refers to a table name

Comment: Well... I mean your second query doesn't even make sense. So it's kind of hard to answer. I think you are taking a VERY special case where a subquery can reference a value from its parent (a correlated subquery) and trying to apply that VERY special case as a more general pattern than it is. This type of generic aliasing/referencing is a pattern in languages like `sql++` but you just don't encounter that much.

Comment: I always thought of it as sub query is evaluated first then results are passed to the main query so each sub query is a “separate being”, this way the alias is not visible to the parser. I’m not able find any information on this though

Comment: Hi @lukaszberwid the explanation is in the two answers below...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would a question like this get downvoted?

Comment: Your assumptions about evaluation order are incorrect. It is true that often a subquery will be evaluated first since, generally, the results of the outer/parent query rely on the subquery's results. However, in the case of a correlated subquery the subquery is dependent on the outer query and so it will be executed later on. Essentially your natural language SQL code is being turned into execution steps by your RDBMS. It's often times impossible to guess at what those steps are by just looking at the SQL itself. Statistics, indexes, post-parsing query rewrites and other logic figure in.

Comment: @JNevill I'm a bit confused why the database can identify `B.col1`, but at the same time table `B` doesn't exists.

Comment: It is confusing. It's just not how it works though. A subquery is only able to reference a table alias of it's outer query to perform a correlated lookup. It is literally saying *"For this one `col1` value for the table aliased `B` in the outer query find the 1 corresponding result set row from this subquery's SQL statement"*. And that's the only time you can use an alias in a subquery in such a way. It's part of the ANSI SQL standard where your desired use of the table alias in the `FROM` clause of the subquery is not part of the spec and is therefore not honored. A CTE would be the right way

Comment: Like I mentioned above though, there are derivations of SQL where such an aliasing may be allowed like `SQL++` or one of it's downstream languages like `PartiQL` et al. Essentially though, the answer is that it's not in the standard and no RDBMS's have implemented logic to allow what you are wanting to do, at least the way you are wanting to do it.

Comment: Also as I mentioned above your SQL code is very abstracted from what happens on the bare metal. Your SQL is parsed, interpreted, and optimized before it's turned into actual instructions for the database to execute. The developers of each RDBMS product determine how their RDBMS performs those steps and how closely they follow the ANSI SQL Standard(s). No RDBMS that I've encountered has expanded past the ANSI SQL Standard to allow table aliases to be references in a subquery's `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your second query you are trying to select from the table that does not exist and in your first query you are referring to the column that does.

In both query's the B and the A letters are only aliases not tables.
Having that in mind, lets remove the aliases in the second query:

```
select col1, col2 from dummy
where col1 = (select col1 from  where col1 = 'aa' limit 1);
```

Do you see something missing now in the query structure ?

To conclude, from your question it seems you do not understand which B is the problem. This one: `FROM B` and not this one `where B.col1`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm a bit confused why the database can identify `B.col1`, but at the same time table `B` doesn't exists.

Comment: B is an alias and as such it is given to a table named dummy and you can use it to reach columns but you can not use that alias as a table. You have not created table B, you have created table dummy.

Answer (score 4):

Because the first reference is a *correlated* reference.  A table alias is a reference to a particular "instance" of a table in the query, not another "table" itself.

If you want that ability, use a CTE:

```
with b as (
      select d.*
      from dummy d
     )
```

Then you can use `b` multiple times in the ensuing query.

Comment: Hi, master! :) thanks for responding. I'm aware of CTE. But, curious why I can't use `B`. So, essentially you're saying that `FROM` is always looking for a logical table. But, how can it allow the usage of instance in the first `FROM` clause?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why the database can identify `B.col1`, but at the same time table `B` doesn't exists.

Comment: @Bla . . . . `b` (as you use it) is a *reference* to one instance of the table.  A *reference* cannot be used as a table.